# Newspaper3k: how to retrieve cashed articles?

Tags: python-newspaper, newspaper3k

This [document](https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/quickstart.html#building-a-news-source) says that that by default, newspaper caches all previously extracted articles and eliminates any article which it has already extracted.

```
>>> cbs_paper = newspaper.build('http://cbs.com')
>>> cbs_paper.size()
1030

>>> cbs_paper = newspaper.build('http://cbs.com')
>>> cbs_paper.size()
2
```

Okay, but it says nothing if I build once a website how I can retrieve the cashed articles?

Answer (score 2):

newspaper3k uses memoize to cache the articles for a source

setting memoize to false would stop the caching mechanism

```
cbs_paper = newspaper.build('http://cbs.com', memoize_articles=False)
```

however, if you still want the caching and want to access the cached articles you can find .newspaper_scraper dir inside the temp folder
(Path in windows machine)

```
C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Temp\.newspaper_scraper\memoized
```

For Linux-based OSes, try looking in

```
/tmp/.newspaper_scraper/memoized/
```

For macOS, look in the directory [specified by `$TMPDIR`](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview#newspaper-article-caching). This may be [any or none of the following](https://osxdaily.com/2018/08/17/where-temp-folder-mac-access/):

```
/tmp/.newspaper_scraper/memoized/
/private/tmp/.newspaper_scraper/memoized/
~/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/.newspaper_scraper/memoized/
```